# I want to use the query builder to implement virtual fields (AS) with a value for the argument

Tags: cakephp

Thank you for all your help.

I'm building an application in CakePHP4 that handles maps.

I want to get the values that are within a reference center point from the DB.

The SQL you want to execute is as follows

```sql
SELECT id, place, lng, lat,
(6378 * acos(
cos(radians(Base latitude)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) – radians(Base latitude))
+ sin(radians(Base latitude)) * sin(radians(lat))))
AS distance FROM test HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance
```

I know that you can write pure SQL and execute it with "$connection->execute($sql, $bind)->fetchAll('assoc')".
But I want to run it in Cake's query builder. I've done some research. I found out that I can create a virtual field in my model with a `protected function __getSocial(){`. But I can't pass any arguments to it.
I want to write the code that I tried, but I don't have anything to write because I don't understand it at all.
Please help me out....

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: read `https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#Cake\ORM\Entity::set`

Comment: Virtual fields have no effect at all on the SQL queries, they are purely PHP code that is run on the entity after it has been loaded from the database.

Comment: See distance finder in https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-geo

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Salines, Greg Schmidt and mark. It's been very helpful, and it has broadened my perspective on Cake. Thank you so much for your comments.

Comment: Salines,Isn't the stuff you set in Entity::set not usable in the query builder's where clause?